# Obtaining the forecasted future values for a time series using neural networks in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, time-series, forecasting

I have a dataset of 60 points. I have supplied 58 points as input data to a NAR network in Matlab(using NNToolbox) and tried developing a model which would help me forecast the next two values. I wish to know how to obtain the next two forecasted values generated by the model in Matlab using NNToolbox. I didn't find any option in NNToolbox for the same.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have only 60 points? Or you have 58 points * n times?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about NNToolbox in MATLAB, but for your dataset, I believe that you would need to train a Recurrent Neural Net (RNN) with the training examples. A RNN should forecast (by regression) the values generated by the model. And there are many tutorials available for building a RNN for regression.